# BLE gattServer.write() overloaded function

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, mbed

I'm having an issue trying to update the value of a characteristic within a custom BLE service that's running on an MCU running `mbedOS v5.8.6`. I am attempting to update the value of this characteristic with the value from a sensor. Please see the function below:

```
void onDataReadCallback(const GattReadCallbackParams *eventDataP) {
    if (eventDataP->handle == dhtServicePtr->dataStream.getValueHandle()) {

        const uint8_t data = sensorData;

        BLE::Instance().gattServer().write(eventDataP->handle, &data, sizeof(data), false);   
    }
}
```

I have tried explicitly stating the correct variable type ([according to the BLE gattServer reference docs](https://os.mbed.com/docs/v5.8/mbed-os-api-doxy/class_gatt_server.html#a7bd0af459475d4c8ee1cd42d659af9d0)) to no avail.

The exact error I receive is:

```
Error: No instance of overloaded function "GattServer::write" matches the argument list in "main.cpp", Line: 135, Col: 39
```

I believe I am doing this correctly according to the afforementioned documentation. So, my question is, where exactly am I going wrong? It's entirely possible that I've just made a stupid mistake!

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: I think sizeof won't return uint16_t, try to typecast it to uint16_t then check it. As function signature requires uint16_t

Comment: @yadhu I've tried specifically casting `sizeof(data)` to a `uint16_t` only to receive the same error unfortunately!

Comment: I hope my answer solves your problem. If it does then accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying send pointer to constant, Although the function signature requires normal pointer. In the below example when value const then compiler will through error.

```
#include <iostream>

    void test(int *ptr)
    {
        printf("%d",*ptr);
    }


    int main ()
    {
        //const int a = 10; //Gives error
        int a = 10;       //This works fine.

        test(&a);

        return 0;
    }
```